# Shouldn't the deleted questions always be visible to their authors, regardless of the author's reputation?

Tags: support, feature-request, moderation

I have a question about my Academia Stack Exchange post: [Circumventing the funding limitations of my potential supervising faculty for Master's project](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90612/circumventing-the-funding-limitations-of-my-potential-supervising-faculty-for-ma)

I'm used to IRC & various other discussion forums, but relatively new to Academia Stack Exchange.

So apparently I had a slightly odd question or maybe the way I framed it was so convoluted. Later, I read the community guidelines for framing a good question.

Meanwhile, my first question was gaining down-votes and was put on hold by community members. So I decided to frame the question more precisely on a later stage when I can find more relevant context.

Therefore my question gained some delete votes/ automatically deleted by the community apparently and was hidden from the posts.

My question here is that (according to community help centre),

**What happens when a post is deleted?**

**Once a post has been deleted, it will disappear for all users except developers, moderators, and users with over 10,000 reputation. Deleted questions will also always be visible to their authors, regardless of the author's reputation. However, deleted posts can be undeleted by casting undelete votes. Once a post has 3 undelete votes, it will no longer be deleted.
Self-deleted posts can be viewed, edited, and undeleted by their original authors.**

**Please note that deleted questions do not appear in search results, so if you wish to later undelete a question that you've deleted you must have saved the URL somewhere.**

I was able to recover my question's URL through Google's cached preview. But shouldn't there be a better way of archived access to new or naive users, who might not be good with searching for archived contents?

Because I wasn't aware that I can't review a deleted post if there's no manual URL save to the same.

Thank you.

Comment: Does it show up on your  profile page: https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/74495/radex-μical-cradox?tab=questions

Comment: No it doesn't. That's why I brought up this issue, here in meta, in the first place. 

However, I was able to access through recent inbox messages linking to the closed question. 

And of course, through manual URL access as well, as mentioned above.

Thank you for pitching in @StrongBad

Comment: You should be able to still see _recent_ deleted questions, regardless of reputation: https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/74495 (there is a "deleted recent questions" link in your profile)

Comment: @ff524 Thank you for the link.
But I already have a bookmark to the same. Also, believe me, there's no such link on my profile page or anywhere else for that matter. I double cross verified before posting this comment to be exact. I'll check again though, but I can't find any such.

Comment: @ff524 Okay, I found this interesting simple bug (I would rather mark it as a design negligence, but nothing serious enough though) relating to this topic. I've included screenshots of the same to make things more clear. Check this out.

Comment: ![Valid XHTML] (https://goo.gl/o7ovig)

![Valid XHTML] (https://goo.gl/e4asmi)

The screenshots are my profile view of my questions on both AC.SE & AC-Meta.

As there's no question asked yet, other than my first question on AC.SE  the link doesn't show up, whereas that's not the case with AC-Meta. 

I'm able to access recently deleted questions on AC-Meta though that, though I don't have any deleted questions on that community.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has essentialy been asked on the main meta [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)

With 765 up votes on the question and 365 on the top answer, I think the answer is that the community feels that they should be visible. That said, the question is [status-declined](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined) so apparently the SE team feels otherwise. It sounds like it is a design choice and not a technical limitation.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. 

It's a shame though that SE team thoughts contradicts with that of it's community users.

I thought of searching for the same question on main meta. But apparently, went ahead with asking it myself, here on this meta.

Thank you @StrongBad

And apologies for not upvoting. [As you can see, I don't have enough reputation score to reflect the same.]

Comment: @RadexμIcalCradoxR it is a little more complicated. It sounds like they have tried it in the past with bad results. Basically the issue is if you have a question with lots of up votes that gets deleted, this makes users mad. To constantly remind them of it everyone they look at their profile is worse, or so the argument goes. Not sure if I believe it.

Comment: @RadexμIcalCradoxR also, welcome to AC.SE. Don't worry so much about getting a question closed, it doesn't mean your next one won't be better.

Comment: Thank you @StrongBad 

And I'm not sure either if I can believe that as well LOL!

Comment: And moreover, shouldn't the access privilege to such things be limited to the profile's owner and not simply to anyone who visits their profile. I mean it's already visible to developers, moderators, and users with over 10,000 reputation. So I guess it shouldn't be a problem with other's seeing that as well unless the question is too localized or individual-centric, which is not recommended for this platform I guess.

Comment: It was declined by Jeff Atwood, who posted an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53297/209901) saying: _Generally when things get deleted, it's for a good reason, and we don't want users to be undeleting them -- there's a reason we require 10k rep to "see" deleted items at all, and only moderators can see deletions in a user's profile_. He got +42 and -238 so far for this answer, so in general community does not agree with him.

Comment: @fedorqui Couldn't agree more with the community's reaction towards that answer. Guess that could have also been the potential candidate for most down-votes on a single answer, LOL!

Comment: @RadexμIcalCradox I think this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes/33949#33949) of Atwoods probably has more down votes, but at least that one is [tag:status-completed].

Comment: @StrongBad Apparently, this guy has got a forte for getting on community's nerve. Nothing offensive though. And yeah, that's why I marked it as a potential candidate, you never know who might pop up with such calibre.

Comment: Maybe it's his niche. After all, he was part of the SE development associates. Now that he left SE, he still can continue being stringent as a moderator. Every community needs a nostalgic warden after all, LOL!